# Change a button value with js in a JSP

Tags: javascript, java, html, jsp

I have a link list generate dynamically in a form in the type of

```
    <%String param = acc.selectByUsername(listamit.get(l)).getUsername();%>
    <a href="#<%=acc.selectByUsername(listamit.get(l)).getUsername()%>" onclick="myFunction('<%=param%>')" data-toggle="tab">
```

it insert in the "a" href and id of the type #username
when i click on each different link i want to call a function that it`s in the head:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        myFunction(str){
            document.getElementById("send_mess_btn").value = str;
        }
    </script>
```

and change the value of this button that is a submit of a form to use it as a parameter in a servlet:

```
    <form action="insert_message?chat=yes" method="post">
       <input type="text" class="form-control" name="text_send_mess" placeholder="Scrivi il tuo messaggio">
       <span class="input-group-btn">
          <button class="btn btn-default" id="send_mess_btn" value="" type="submit">Invia</button>         
       </span>
    </form>
```

This don`t work for me.. so thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try delegation and do not follow the link

```
document.getElementById("someContainerId").addEventListener("click", e => {
  const tgt = e.target;
  if (!tgt.matches('data-toggle')) return; // not a link
  e.preventDefault(); // stop the click on the link
  document.getElementById('send_mess_btn').value = this.dataset.username;
})
```

where you have changed the link to

```
 <a href="#<%=acc.selectByUsername(listamit.get(l)).getUsername()%>" data-username="<%=param%>" data-toggle="tab">
```

change

```
getElementById("someContainerId")
```

to a selector that is the nearest static container selector to the links